# Javascript - Can't push an array to 2D array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I read a file line by line, turn each line into an array of number and push that array to a 2D array. But when I logged that 2D array, it was empty. I really don't know what's wrong here.

Here is my code:

```
var readline = require('readline');
var fs = require('fs');

var interface = readline.createInterface({
    input: fs.createReadStream('dataset.csv')
});

var transactions = []; // declare the 2d array
interface.on('line', function (line) {
    var str = line.trim().split(' ').map(Number); // turn each line to a number array
    transactions.push(str); // push that number array to the 2d array
});

console.log(transactions);
```

Comment: One line: `[ 112, 162, 224, 368, 395, 527, 568, 613, 788, 798, 805, 814, 913, 988 ]`, no error at all, the result is just `[]`

Comment: Base on the suggested question, I think there might be something about how nodejs work with the IO. It printed the array first while the file was still being read, perhaps

Comment: `interface.on('line',` is async, you cannot console.log the transactions where you are logging them. Instead `interface.on('close', function () {
    console.log(transactions);
});`